# Loading .bdf files in EEGLAB

Tags: matlab, loading, eeglab

A .bdf file is not loading properly into [EEGLAB](https://sccn.ucsd.edu/eeglab/index.php).

I have trying to recreate the procedures of an EEGLAB experiment. Here, .bdf files were imported using the BIOSIG interface producing a result like so:

[image]

However, when I upload these files using this interface I get this result:

[image]

Note that there is some differences here (like the epochs), but primary concern is that not all the channel data appears to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific channel frequency data will not be visible until you run a high-pass filter to remove high frequency noise - doing so will reveal the signal from each specific channel.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if you select Remove DC offset in your channel data plot will reveal all the signals.